# Pull XML nodeValue into php Variable

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodevalue

I am trying to assign the `<all>` / `<avg>` value in this XML code to a variable, so that I can use it for calculations.  But when I do this, and try to print the value, I get a blank screen.  Can someone please help?

```
<stats>
    <type id="a">
        <buy>
            <volume>698299009</volume>
            <avg>17.94</avg>
            <max>18.45</max>
            <min>1.00</min>     
        </buy>
        <sell>
            <volume>16375234</volume>
            <avg>21.03</avg>
            <max>24.99</max>
            <min>20.78</min>        
        </sell>
        <all>
            <volume>714674243</volume>
            <avg>18.01</avg>
            <max>24.99</max>
            <min>1.00</min>     
        </all>
    </type>
</stats>
```

The php code I am using is as follows:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("values.xml");

$unit_value = $xml->xpath("/stats/type[@id='a']/buy/avg/")->nodeValue;

echo $unit_value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects .. so you can do this :

```
$unit_value = $xml->xpath("//stats//type[@id='a']//buy//avg");
echo (string)$unit_value[0]; // cast to string not required
```

[Working example here](http://codepad.org/hZOuru8X)

or if you are using PHP => 5.4 you can do this :

```
$unit_value = $xml->xpath("//stats//type[@id='a']//buy//avg")[0];
echo $unit_value;
```

[Working example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PlXTZ9)

Comment: Manse, this worked perfectly, thanks!  Is there a way to assign the [0] to $unit_value all in once line?  Something like the following maybe?   $unit_value = $xml->xpath("//stats//type[@id='a']//buy//avg")[0];

Comment: @user1452060 only from PHP 5.4 onwards -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87 - I have updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

Please refer documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), `$xml->xpath` should return you the array. The docs also shows an example of how to access text nodes. Below is an excerpt from the docs

```
<?php
  $string = <<<XML
   <a>
     <b>
       <c>text</c>
       <c>stuff</c>
     </b>
     <d>
       <c>code</c>
     </d>
  </a>
 XML;

 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

 /* Search for <a><b><c> */
 $result = $xml->xpath('/a/b/c');

 while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
   echo '/a/b/c: ',$node,"\n";
 }

 /* Relative paths also work... */
 $result = $xml->xpath('b/c');

 while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
   echo 'b/c: ',$node,"\n";
 }
?>
```

which produces output as

```
/a/b/c: text
/a/b/c: stuff
b/c: text
b/c: stuff
```

which is I suppose exactly what you need.